# doinbackground method gives null values

Tags: android, variables, android-asynctask

i am making an android app in which i am getting the data from the server side by making doinbackground method and assigning these values to the variables which are declared globally. Problem is that i am using that variables in oncreate method where it give me null values because the doinbackground method finishes after the variables are used in oncreate. what could be the solution for this?

```
public void getProfileInfo() {
    String currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery
            .getQuery(ParseConstants.KEY_USER_INFO);
    query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_USER_ID_INFO, currentUserId);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject thisUser : objects) {
                    name = thisUser
                            .getString(ParseConstants.TYPE_INFO_FULLNAME);
                    email = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("Activity", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

i am calling this method in oncreate before i use the variables name and email.i checked the value of name and email. it gave me the right values.

Comment: You can test if the variable not equal to null by a simple if statement

Comment: i have done it...it always gives me null.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Can you post your code and you have to update the view after you change the data

Comment: You should also post onCreate as it's relevant to this question

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a bit of timing problem.

Just to state the obvious, you can't start an asynchronous task on a background thread, and then blindly use the results without knowing that the task has completed.

The use of the results needs to be triggered by the completion of the task.

So, whatever you're doing to access these 'global variables' that is getting nulls - don't do it at a deterministic time (e.g. in onCreate) - do it when you actually get the results back.

If there's a chance that the results may come back before the point where you're currently trying to access them, check to see if they have come back, and if they have, use them. If they haven't, wait until they do come back.

I'll leave the implementation of this as an "exercise for the reader"